# 3D Hough Transform for medical imaging

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, stack, medical

Is there any extension of the Hough Transform (https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) to 3D volumic images (stacks) ? I have (image below) a 3D skeleton on which I want to detect segments. The 3D skeleton was computed using the 'skeletonize_3d()' belonging to te 'skimage' package. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdTJZ.png)

Comment: what stopped you from entering "hough transform 3d" into google?

Comment: I did this. If i'm asking, it's because I searched for days ;)

Comment: I can find stuff if I google that....

Comment: Are you sure that's for 3D stacks and not for 3D point clouds or 3D meshes ?